# how gemfirexd store the table data file greater than its in_memory?

Tags: in-memory-database, gemfire, geode

i have in-memroy of 4GB.the data file iam going to load into GEMFIREXD is of 8GB. how in-memory organize the Remaining data 4 GB data.i read about EVICTION Class but i didn't get any clarification.
While loading the data  it copied into disk OR after filling the 4GB it start coping into disk?

help onthis ..
thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you use the EVICTION clause without using the PERSISTENT clause, the data will start being written to disk once you reach the eviction threshold. The least recently used rows will be written to disk and dropped from memory.

If you have a PERSISTENT table, the data is already on disk when you reach your eviction threshold. At that point, the least recently used rows are dropped from memory.

Note that there is still a per row overhead in memory even if the row is evicted.

Doc reference for details:

http://gemfirexd.docs.pivotal.io/latest/userguide/index.html#overflow/configuring_data_eviction.html
- http://gemfirexd.docs.pivotal.io/latest/userguide/index.html#caching_database/eviction_limitations.html